# Heroku Procfile run command not visible in Resources

Tags: heroku, discord.js, hosting

So, Basically, I was trying to host a discord.js bot on Heroku. For that purpose, I made a Procfile, containing: "worker: node .". On Opening the heroku application on its website, only this was visible[image]

Since its using the web dyno, i am not able to host the bot online. Any help please?

Made procfile, expected a node . run option using worker dynos in heroku. Instead, its not visible, and i am not able to host the bot.
The Procfile ss
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Did you commit that change and redeploy?

Comment: Is the Procfile included in git?
`git add .`
`git commit -am "Add Procfile"`
`git push heroku main`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, i have done all that. I did commit it, and used all those commands.